# Why BitBlt has different result on different place

Tags: winapi, bitblt

I write a test sample for the BitBlt, in WinProc, the WM_PAINT does this: it will repeat draw the small block from window (0,0) to the client area.

```
      case WM_CREATE:{
          cxSource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZE) ;
          cySource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYCAPTION) ;
          return 0 ;

      case WM_PAINT:
          hdcClient = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
          hdcWindow = GetWindowDC (hwnd) ;
          RECT rcClient; 
          GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
          for (y = 0 ; y < rcClient.bottom ; y += cySource)
              for (x = 0 ; x < rcClient.right ; x += cxSource)
                  BitBlt (hdcClient, x, y, cxSource, cySource, hdcWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) ;

          ReleaseDC (hwnd, hdcWindow) ;
          EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
          return 0;
```

But if I write a function do the same thing and mark the above code, the result is one big picture, can anybody tell me why?

This sample is from programming windows CH14 BitBlt project and I modify some. The project target is to use the small pattern from window(0,0,cxSource, cySource) to fill the client area, but if I write this in another function, the result is, only one big picture.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is defined cxSource and cySource? Which part of code mark?

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). What actual problem do you have with blitting between window and client DCs of the same window, in a loop?

Comment: Roman, this code is right. The target is to use the small pattern from window(0,0,cxSource, cySource) to fill the client area

Comment: It's a random image generator, copying an uninitialized part of the window.  You get whatever was underneath the upper left corner of the window.  Trying to guess what is was meant to do is impossible.

Comment: I mean, if the BeginPaint() was write another place, the result I got various different. Sometimes I got nothing all the time.